# Can fetch API from node.js but not from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I am having issues fetching data from an api from the client side. I have verified that you can get data from the api in node.js, python and by going to the url but I get an error when trying to access it from the client.

```js
function fetchData(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((res) => {return res.text()})
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

fetchData("Some url string").then((data) => console.log(data));
```

In node.js this allows me to get the response data but on the client page this returns an error.

Comment: Only use `no-cors` if you want an opaque response. If you actually want a response, don't use `no-cors`

Comment: How are you trying to display the data on the client?

Comment: When I get rid of no-cors:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.